# django MultiValueDictKeyError and RuntimeError in saving a form's data in database

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying it very hard but I didn't find what I am missing. I have made a form that contains fields like the first name, last name, address, city, state, zip and one Image file from the user.

But I am getting this error when I was trying to post data by views.

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /submit_your_task

'image'

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/submit_your_task
Django Version:     2.2.4
Exception Type:     MultiValueDictKeyError
Exception Value:    

'image'
```

and this is my views.py for that form

```
def submit_your_task(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        first_name = request.POST['first_name']
        last_name = request.POST['last_name']
        address = request.POST['address']
        phone = request.POST['phone']
        city = request.POST['city']
        state = request.POST['state']
        zip = request.POST['zip']
        image = request.FILES['image']
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        file = fs.save(image.name, image)
        url = fs.url(file)
        submit_task = SubmitYourTask(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name,
                                     address=address,
                                     phone=phone, city=city,
                                     state=state, zip=zip, image=url)
        submit_task.save()
    return render(request, 'submit_task.html')
```

and this is urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home-page'),
    path('about/', views.about_us, name='about'),
    path('signup/', views.signup, name='signup'),
    path('submit_your_task/', views.submit_your_task, name='submit_your_task'),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

And when I put the slash after 'submit_your_task' it gives me RuntimeError

```
RuntimeError at /submit_your_task

You called this URL via POST, but the URL doesn't end in a slash and you have APPEND_SLASH set. Django can't redirect to the slash URL while maintaining POST data. Change your form to point to 127.0.0.1:8000/submit_your_task/ (note the trailing slash), or set APPEND_SLASH=False in your Django settings.

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/submit_your_task
Django Version:     2.2.4
Exception Type:     RuntimeError
Exception Value:    

You called this URL via POST, but the URL doesn't end in a slash and you have APPEND_SLASH set. Django can't redirect to the slash URL while maintaining POST data. Change your form to point to 127.0.0.1:8000/submit_your_task/ (note the trailing slash), or set APPEND_SLASH=False in your Django settings.
```

Comment: Did you specify `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the `<form>`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem No, does it affects on it?

Comment: without it, you can not send both data and files.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem and should I use action in the form tag?